# How to write a background process for pouchdb sync for a hybrid android app (angularJS) which should run even after app is closed

Tags: android, angularjs, synchronization, background-process, pouchdb

I'm developing an android app (hybird) using ionic framework, angularJS, Nodejs, pouchDB as localDB and couchDB as server DB. App has a requirement to run a background process for pouchdb/couchdb sync for angularJS android app which should run even after app is closed. I know javascript service is not an option because it stops when app is killed. Appreciate any help...!

Comment: you should look https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android, https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android